# Why here the time period of a simple pendulum is taken to be 50 seconds

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, measurements, oscillators, error-analysis

The given question is
[image]

The given answer is
[image]

I want to know why here T is taken to be 50 s

Answer (score 1):

$50\.\rm s$ was the time interval measured with an error of $\pm 0.1\,\rm s$.

The analysis that is shown requires you to know the fractional error in the period, $\Delta T/T$.

From the data $T\pm \Delta T= (50\pm 0.1)/25 = (50/25)\pm(0.1/25)$.
$\Delta T/T = (0.1/25)/(50/25)=0.1/50$.

Because the time interval measured and the error in that time interval are both divided by the same number (of oscillations) the fractional erros in the period is the same as the fractional error in the measured time interval.